# Understanding したことまで

Tags: grammar, particle-まで

The speaker is defending her teacher:

> 「毎日クラス全員のこと、こまかくノートに書いてるんだよ。**会話したことまで**」
>   Every day, in her notebook, she made detailed notes about all the class. *Even as far as conversations.*

Am I correct that verb-ことまで means "to go as far as doing verb"?

I'm not 100% sure about the verb here. Is した just a substitute for 書いた? i.e. is it talking about writing down the conversations, or is it talking about the act of conversing itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

した in 会話した is simply a part of the suru-verb 会話する ("to converse"), which is an intransitive verb that does not take を.

If we took this こと after 会話した as a nominalizer, this would mean "She writes even the fact her classmates conversed", which makes almost no sense to me. The mere fact that "students made a conversation" is not a meaningful piece of information because students do so every day.

So I think this こと simply is "things", and 会話したこと means "the things we conversed *about*", or "the contents of our conversations".

Relative clauses in Japanese can have an adverbial relationship with the modified noun (Type B in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39551/5010)), and can be safely used with intransitive verbs.

Examples:

> - よく行く場所 the place we often go *to*
> - 何か書くもの something to write *with* (eg, a pen)
> - 何か書くこと something to write *about* (eg, an event)
> - 感謝の気持ちを表す言葉 words *with* which I can express my gratitude

Answer (score 0):

According to the dictionary, 会話 can be followed by する.
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/37284/meaning/m0u/%E4%BC%9A%E8%A9%B1/

会話する = to talk
会話した = talked
会話したこと = the fact that I talked
会話したことまで = even the fact that I talked

Strictly speaking, it is talking about the act of conversing itself, but I think it includes the conversations.