# What machine are they talking about here?

Tags: grammar

For full context:
http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011281951000/k10011281951000.html

The sentence in question:
式の話を英語で聞くことができる機械も用意しました。

My attempt at translation:
"They also prepared a machine which can hear the ceremonys speech in english."

First, I am really skeptical of my translation "a machine which can hear...". I'd rather think that this is a machine with which YOU can hear the speech in english too, although this is indeed somehow included in the statement that "the machine" can hear the speech in english.

Second, What machine are they talking about? I think they offer interpreters broadcasting simultaneous interpreting on a channel or something the like. But why is this expressed through the term "machine"??? Or are they talking about a kind of machine I simply have no clue about???^^

Comment: You asked [almost the same question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54666/5010) recently... I think the machine is a simple wireless audio receiver with an earphone. Probably the speech was pre-translated.

Comment: yeah, sorry and thanks for the hint, your explanation from back then helped a lot! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

式の話を英語で聞くことができる is a relative clause modifying 機械. The non-relative version of this noun phrase would be:

> 「その機械**で**、式の話を英語で聞くことができる。」 <sub>(← The subject is unmentioned/implied 人)</sub> 
>   "With that machine, one/you/they can hear the ceremony speeches in English."

To turn it back into the relative phrase:

> 「［式の話を英語で聞くことができる］機械」 <sub>(← で goes missing)</sub> 
>   "A machine [with which one/you/they can hear the ceremony speeches in English]"
>   (i.e. "A device that enables you to hear the ceremony speeches in English")