# How to make sense of 呪縛から解放されるウソという名の魔法

Tags: grammar, expressions, relative-clauses

I'm having problem figuring out the idea or meaning of a sentence while reading manga.

The context is that a character **A** told someone (character **B**) a big lie, and influenced by that lie, **B** started to act in favor of character **A**, without even realizing it. The liar states now that character **B** is under his "spell" (魔法). There's no magic involved, just an expression.

After that, character **A** says:

> 呪縛{じゅばく}から解放{かいほう}されるウソという名{な}の魔法{まほう}

I'm able to understand each word individually but not as a whole phrase. What is the main idea of the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 呪縛から解放されるウソという名の魔法
>   (It's) A magic called 'Lie', which unleashes you from the curse.

- 呪縛から解放される: "with which one is unleashed from the bond/curse". This is an adverbial-head relative clause that modifies ウソという名の魔法. 呪縛 is something that binds you psychologically.

  - [How is the subject of this subclause made clear?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54666/5010)
- ウソという名の: "of the name *lie*"
- 魔法: "magic". The sentence is a 体言止め sentence.

  - [what exactly is "体言止{たいげんど}め"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/5010)

Comment: I can't explain why, but I feel that 'unleash' sounds a little odd here. I would prefer 'release' or 'liberate'. Examples where 'unleash' works: "He unleashed his curse (upon the world).", "Unleash the dogs.". A definition from the Cambridge dictionary: "to suddenly release a violent force that cannot be controlled "