# How to say "the one I sent the letter to"

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, nominalization, giving-and-receiving, cleft-sentences

I sent him the letter - 彼に手紙を送ってあげた

He was the one who sent me the letter - 手紙を送ってくれたのは、彼だった

He was the one I sent the letter to - ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say **私が手紙を送ったのは彼だった**.

This 私が is more or less important. If you omitted 私が, the sentence would become ambiguous:

> 手紙を送ったのは彼だった。
>
> - He is the one who sent a letter (to someone).
> - He is the one I sent a letter to.

The use of あげる cannot solve this type of ambiguity (手紙を送ってあげたのは彼だった is still ambiguous the same way). And even the following simple phrase is ambiguous in Japanese:

> 手紙を送った人
>
> - a person who sent a letter (to someone) (=the sender)
> - a person who someone sent a letter to (=the receiver)

Please read the following questions for details:

- [Clarification about how 惚れた should be translated](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60895/5010)
- [Relative Clause Ambiguous](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60385/5010)
- [How is the subject of this subclause made clear?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54666/5010)